# combined foreach not displaying all array values in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to display 2 arrays with a foreach loop, but for some reason when the values in the arrays are set to 0, only the last item of the array is displaying

Say I have the following array values:

```
users array ( 0 => user1, 1 => user2)
occurrences array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 3)   //the key represents the user from the users array
```

The output of the foreach loop will display correctly

```
//output
user1 0
user2 3
```

However, if both values are 0 only user2 will be displayed

```
users array ( 0 => user1, 1 => user2)
occurrences array ( 0 => 0, 1 => 0);   //the key represents the user from the users array

//output (should also display user1 0)
user2 0
```

This is my foreach loop.

```
?>
<table>
<th>User</th><th># of Occurrences</th>
<?
foreach (array_combine($occurrences, $users) as $occur => $user){
    ?>
    <tr><td><? echo $user; ?></td><td><? echo $occur; ?></td></tr>
    <?
}
?></table>
<?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question is performing the following:

> *For each occurrence value key, provide a user.*

I would imagine you are after the opposite behaviour:

> *For each user key, provide an occurrence value*

Try swapping `$occurrences` and `$users` in the call, i.e.,

`array_combine($users, $occurrences)`

The reason you are only seeing user2 is because array_combine considers the entries `0 => 0 and 1 => 0` and will receive `0 0` as a key list. Therefore, it can only produce a single key in the resulting array hash (it is using the values from the occurrences array to build the key list).

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = array(1 => 'user2', 0 => 'user1');
$occurences = array(0 => 0, 1 => 3);

$count = count($users);
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
  $result[$users[$i]] = $occurences[$i];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Notice $users array order. Using array_combine, you would get wrong values in this case.

```
array (size=2)
  'user1' => int 0
  'user2' => int 3
```

I can't reproduce what you are saying:

```
var_dump(array_combine([0 => 'user_1', 1 => 'user_2'], [0 => 0, 1 => 0]));
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  'user_1' => int 0
  'user_2' => int 0
```

Comment: So a for loop is the way to go? The users array will always be in the same order as the occurrences. I use array_push from a sql query to insert values into the arrays. They will never be reversed like the example you gave. Regardless, a for loop works. I still don't get why it isn't displaying both users.

Comment: @user1852176 There are other ways too, but I would do it "manually", you can't rely on a function if you are not completely familiar with it. I assume $key is a link between user and occurrence, so in this case, order doesn't matter, if you use some array_* function, I'm sure it will.

Comment: @user1852176 You reversed arrays like it was said.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to do it in some fashion like this:

```
<?php
foreach($users as $userId => $userName) {
 if(isset($occurrences[$userId])) {
?>
  <tr><td><?php echo $userName; ?></td><td><?php echo $occurrences[$userId]; ?></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That adds the values of the arrays together so the output is entirely different.

Comment: Good point, I modified my answer now that I understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an associative array if your keys are merely following numbers?

this worked for me:

```
<?php 
$user = array('user1','user2');
$occur = array(0,0);

foreach (array_combine($user, $occur) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " : " . $value;
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if both values are 0

then, you have two same keys for two different values and you overwrite first value with the second value; therefore, in the array, there is just one value

Answer (score 0):

PHP's combining the *values* in `$occurances` for use as the array key in the resulting combined array. Since you have specified `0` as the value twice, `user2` will always assume the first position in the array.

For your solution, would this not be better:

```
foreach($occurances as $userindex => $occurs)
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$users[$userindex].'</td><td>'.$occurs.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not do

```
if(count($occurrences)==count($users)){
    foreach($occurences as $k, $v){
        ?><tr><td><? echo $users[$k]; ?></td><td><? echo $v; ?></td></tr><?
    }
}
```

Confirms the size of both arrays match, then achieves the desired output.

Comment: Because `$occurrences.length` == `length`... The `if` statement is **always** true. And you're using short tags. I guess your question should probably have been 'Why do'... :P

Comment: @BenM what? Please explain what you're getting at, because that doesn't make a lick of sense.

Comment: Run your code on a server. `echo $occurences.length;` outputs the string `length`. Therefore you're comparing two strings, which are both `length`.

Comment: >.< Attentiveness is key. Answer has been edited. Had my head stuck in Javascript mode. As for the short tags, I used them because the Asker used them. (sorry for time jump. actually had to do work for a moment there) @BenM